# How to include @mixin from one sass file to another sass file in different folder

Tags: css, sass, ionic3

I am including a mixin from one SASS file into another file but I've got an error with the ionic `serve` command:

```
Error: "Sass Error
Invalid CSS after " @include": expected identifier, was '"../../../theme/mai'"
```

This is the file where I am importing the mixin:

```
action-sheet-layout-1 { 
    @include '../../../theme/main.scss' 
    @include "settingAnimationHeader"; // this mixin is defined in main.scss

    [button-action-shit] {
        z-index: 99999; right: 16px; top: 56px;
        ...
    }
```

The mixin as defined in `main.scss`:

```
@mixin settingAnimationHeader { 
    @keyframes headerOff { 
        from { 
            background-color: theme-colors('mainColors', 'primary'); 
        } 
        to {
            background-color: transparent;
        } 
    }
...
}
```

I am new to ionic and SASS, is what I am doing right or am I missing something?

The directory structure of both files from the app root:

```sh
src/theme/main.scss # the mixin is defined in this file.
src/components/action-sheet/layout-1/action-sheet-layout-1.scss # the mixin is imported here.
```

Answer (score 15):

**2021 update**

> The Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule. Sass will gradually phase it out over the next few years, and eventually remove it from the language entirely. Prefer the @use rule instead.

So as per the situation here , the code should be changed **from**

`@import 'path/to/main.scss'` //*Note: make sure that you name your sass partials starting with an underscore(_), this way sass knows that its not meant to be compiled to a css file and you also don't need to include the extension as seen here, instead change it*

**to**

`@use 'path/to/main' as m` //*where 'm' is a reference variable or namespace to your partial.which BTW is optional but recommended.*

You can find more about it here: [Sass-docs/imports](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

Comment: [`@import` vs `@use` in details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62757625/104380)

Answer (score 12):

at the top of your SASS file (`action-sheet-layout-1.scss`) you need to include: `@import "../../../theme/main.scss"` then you can access the mixins inside `main.scss` by doing `@include settingAnimationHeader;` inside the css rule where you want to apply this mixin

Answer (score 7):

You can **rename your main.scss file to _main.scss**

The prefix '_' tells the sass/scss compiler that this file is a **partial**. And so, the compiler will not try to compile the file.

[Sass partials](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4)

Answer (score 2):

If the mixins are defined in *main.scss* just make sure to import the file before the file they are used in ie *action-sheet-layout-1.scss* in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For angular application

Create or rename the file with prefix `_` eg _main.scss. Thats tells the sass/scss compiler that this file is a partial.

**_style.scss**

```
$sizes: 3, 7, 20, 33,37,40;

@mixin width-classes {
  @each $i in $sizes {
    $width: $i +'% !important';
    .w-#{$i} {
      width: #{$width};
    }
  }
}
@include width-classes;
```

In the other scss file, import the scss file.
**app.scss**

```
@import '../../../../../../style';
```