# What's the difference between @import and @use SCSS rules?

Tags: css, sass

When to use SCSS rule: **`@use`** and when to use **`@import`**?
What is the difference between them and the best-case scenarios to use them?

```scss
@use '_styles.scss'; 
@import '_styles.scss';
```

Comment: FYI: if someone needs more info regarding the working of @use can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71426623/whats-the-difference-between-only-use-and-use-as-scss-rules/77711810#77711810

Answer (score 139, accepted):

> The new `@use` is similar to `@import`. but has some notable differences:
>
> - The file is only imported once, no matter how many times you `@use` it in a project.
> - Variables, mixins, and functions (what Sass calls "members") that start with an underscore (_) or hyphen (-) are considered private, and not imported.
> - Members from the used file (buttons.scss in this case) are only made available locally, but not passed along to future imports.
> - Similarly, `@extends` will only apply up the chain; extending selectors in imported files, but not extending files that import this one.
> - All imported members are namespaced by default.

https://css-tricks.com/introducing-sass-modules/

<s>`@import` will be deprecated in favor of `@use` and `@forward`, and support [will be dropped](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/master/accepted/module-system.md#timeline) by October 2022 at the latest.</s>

**July 2022 update:**

> In light of the fact that LibSass was deprecated before ever adding support for the new module system, the timeline for deprecating and removing @import has been pushed back. We now intend to wait until 80% of users are using Dart Sass (measured by npm downloads) before deprecating @import, and wait at least a year after that and likely more before removing it entirely.

**March 2023 update:**

> As week of Mar 06 to Mar 12, the npm downloads of the sass and node-sass packages are 11,700,729 and 2,831,234 respectively, meaning we have reached 80.5% adoption rate for Dart Sass, which is above the target for making the deprecation @import current.