# What's the difference between only @use and @use as * SCSS rules?

Tags: sass

What's the difference?

@use 'scss/my'

and

@use 'scss/my' as *

I think it's same, isn't no use namespace, right?
but is it difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Choosing a Namespace](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace) doc explains clearly.

> By default, a module’s namespace is just the last component of its URL without a file extension. However, sometimes you might want to choose a different namespace—you might want to use a shorter name for a module you refer to a lot, or you might be loading multiple modules with the same filename. You can do this by writing `@use "<url>" as <namespace>`.

> You can even load a module without a namespace by writing `@use "<url>" as *`. We recommend you only do this for stylesheets written by you, though; otherwise, they may introduce new members that cause name conflicts!

Answer (score 1):

In Simple terms both syntax are used for different use cases, as of now when we use `@use` then everything contained in that particular file becomes **namespaced** by default i.e you have to prefix **namespace** name which you have used and if you don't mention any namespace then by default it will be the file name as shown in below images(Note: the **.css** is the output generated for **.scss** file).

**Implicit/Default Behaviour**
[image]

**Under the Hood (what actually it mean when we don't mention any namespace name)**
[image]

**Any other namespace name**
[image]

**No Namespace (Not Recommended!!)**
[image]

## Additional Info

**Let's think about why namespace is important?**

Primarly it help to avoid **bugs**/**conflicts** and help us to divide all the **.scss** file efficiently.

Lets consider a case we have more than 1 partial files having same variable name which we are using without using namespace

[image]

Fix for above issue to either set the namespace for any 1 file or both. Generally most of the projects contains several partial files to **segregate** styles in a project to make it more **scalable in future**. Below shown directory structure is how i have divided the whole styles(**Only Global Style**) for particular client's project, If we try to avoid namespace it may cause some unexpected result. Thanks

[image]