# How to @use use in Scss Files TO access to all files

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-lint

i was trying to change @import to @use in SCSS file
But i am getting this error

please help!

[image]

[image]

Compilation Error
Error: Invalid CSS after "...size: variables": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$title-font-size;"
on line 6 of sass/i:\VS-Code\Working On\Architrct\scss\main.scss

> > font-size: variables.$title-font-size;

How to @use use in Scss Files TO access to all files

Comment: try with this way `font-size: $title-font-size;`

Comment: Compilation Error
Error: Undefined variable: "$title-font-size".
        on line 5 of sass/i:\VS-Code\Working On\Architrct\scss\main.scss
>>     font-size: $title-font-size;

Comment: If you want to use a namespaced variable, like `variables.$foo`, you'll need to define the namespace in your import declaration. `@use "./componts/variables" as variables;`. Also, do you use a compiler allowing `@use` ?

Comment: The comand line tells you that `variables` is not a valid expression. That means that you have to provide a real `$variable`. In other words, you are trying to apply an entire .scss file as a value, insted a real value. As @Amuary says, you have to select the variable you want inside variables document.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ya after reading the all of comment i check my code one more time as  @toni said i need to declare my variable as global

Comment: here is detailed solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71426623/whats-the-difference-between-only-use-and-use-as-scss-rules/77711810#77711810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
@use '../componts/variables' as *;
```

Comment: @GauravMali Here is a video that may help you to understand use and forward  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR-a8upNjJ0&list=PLlwbAGSVMKHrkw8qJHSXePgvYRwy9i-8Q&index=74&t=1s