# scss file import getting error after angular and bootstrap upgrade

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, jhipster

I created a jhipster application. It got created with angular version 14. Later i upgraded it to 16. but running "ng build" throws error on the below line.

```
@import '~bootswatch/dist/materia/variables';
// Override Bootstrap variables
@import 'bootstrap-variables';
// Import Bootstrap source files from node_modules
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~bootswatch/dist/materia/bootswatch';
```

I am issue this error in files "vendor.scss, global.scss, navbar.component.scss and docs.component.scss"

I was able to fix it by changing the path to relative path, like,

```
@import '../../../../../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/materia/variables';
// Override Bootstrap variables
@import 'bootstrap-variables';
// Import Bootstrap source files from node_modules
@import '../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '../../../../../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/materia/bootswatch';
```

But I am not sure this is the right approach. can someone advise? Also i am not sure exactly when did the error occurred. i upgraded angular from "14.2.0" to "16.1.3" and bootstrap from "13.0.0" to "15.0.1".

Comment: You might try creating a new JHipster app with v8 beta and see how it's done there. v8 uses Angular 16.

Answer (score 0):

Someonthing somewhat new in SCSS is [the `@use` at-rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/). Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757419/whats-the-difference-between-import-and-use-scss-rules) to read more about the differences.

So this is obviously untested since I don't have you app, but I think you might be able to do this:

```scss
@use '~bootswatch/dist/materia/variables' as *;
// Override Bootstrap variables
@use 'bootstrap-variables' as *;
// Import Bootstrap source files from node_modules
@use '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap' as *;
@use '~bootswatch/dist/materia/bootswatch' as *;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in Angular 14, you should have a warning indicating that using ~ in Sass imports is deprecated.
You can do `@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'` directly if you have defined

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

in your `angular.json` file.