# Is there a way to create global variables in scss?

Tags: reactjs, sass, styling

I want to create a group of variables in my Home.scss file that I can reuse in other scss files without having to re-type or copy and paste those variables in the other scss files.

Is there a way I can do this?

```
$Matte-P-1: #572991;
$Matte-P-2: #7550A6;
$Matte-P-3: #68369B;
```

I want these variables to work in my Home.scss, component.scss, and nav.scss.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try to use them in those files ? were you not able to access ?

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables/

Comment: move your variables to another file so you can import them from different files, they will be accessible if you're importing all your files into one `main.scss` file that imports your other files (like `nav.scss` and `component.scss`) into it, but would need to know more about the folder structure and how those SCSS files are imported

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of different methods to do this, but it's relatively easy to achieve the desired effect.

### Method 1 - Import into each SCSS file needed

Create a file (e.g. `constants.scss`) and import that into each of your component SCSS files.

```
    ├── components/
    ├── styles/
    │   ├── component.scss
    │   ├── constants.scss
    │   ├── home.scss
    │   ├── nav.scss
```

```scss
// constants.scss

$Matte-P-1: #572991;
// ...
```

Then in another file (such as `nav.scss`):

```scss
// nav.scss
@use "./constants"
// @use or @import "path_to_constants_file"

.myClass {
  background-color: $Matte-P-1
}
```

FYI: I've used `@import` here as it is the recomeneded option [see this question discussing the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757419/whats-the-difference-between-import-and-use-scss-rules)

Pro:

- Allows you to place each SCSS file alongside the component (as long as you import the constants file accordingly (you may have the above directory structure, or below, either of which is fine as it's just about getting the imports correct)

  ```
   ├── components/
   │   ├── Home/
   │   |   ├── home.jsx
   │   |   ├── home.scss
   │   ├── Nav/
   │   |   ├── nav.jsx
   │   |   ├── home.scss
  ```

Con:

- The trade-off to this solution is that you need to import it into every new SCSS file you create and want to use the variables for (which can easily be forgotten)

### Method 2 - A "main" SCSS file

Having one port of call for your SCSS is sometimes preferred, and your directory may look like this:

```
    ├── components/
    ├── styles/
    │   ├── component.scss
    │   ├── constants.scss
    │   ├── home.scss
    │   ├── main.scss
    │   ├── nav.scss
```

The `constants.scss` file would look the same as you first example, and the `main.scss` would look something like this:

```scss
// main.scss

// import global style/variables
@import "./constants"
// ...

// import component  style
@import "./component"
@import "./home"
@import "./nav"
// ...
```

Then in `App.jsx` you would import only the `main.scss` file.

Pro:

- Any changes to the `main.scss` or `constants.scss` files are automatically available to the other files (this is dependant on order, hence why `constants` is imported first before the components)
- Only one import path of `main.scss` into your `App.jsx`

Con:

- The trade-off to this solution is that it seems much more monolithic now in that all the SCSS is being imported into one main file and then being used