# Use a scss class from a file in another scss file

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a day/night theme button that changes the main body color in `App.scss` in my React project. It's simple, it uses `body.light` and `body.dark`, but I also need to change some text in my navigation bar, which is in a different folder with `Navbar.jsx` and `Navbar.scss`. Because of how the button is made, I can only change `App.scss`, so how can I export/add the class from `Navbar.scss` (which is `.site-nav`) into my `App.scss` so i can add `.site-nav.dark / .site-nav.light`  for it to work?

I tried renaming it to `_Navbar.scss`, adding `@mixin`:

```
@mixin nav {
  //code
  .site-nav {
    //code
  }
}
```

and I tried adding this to my `App.scss`:

```
@use './Navbar/Navbar.scss' as Navi;

body.dark {
  color: #a58c6f;
  background-color: #1c221f;
  @include Navi.site-nav;
}
```

but I get `Invalid CSS after "  @include Navi": expected "}", was  ".site-nav;"`Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include @mixin from one sass file to another sass file in different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392981/how-to-include-mixin-from-one-sass-file-to-another-sass-file-in-different-folde)

Comment: I tried following this, also doing it with a @use but no use. I also edited my question for clarity.

Comment: As an aside, you can use use './Navbar/Navbar.scss' as Navi; like this @use './Navbar/Navbar.scss' as *; and skip using the placeholder. Also, you need to forward the file you intend to use. Look up Sass-lang.com and it will show you how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are importing Navbar.scss with @use you don't need to @include, all classes inside Navbar will be available in into your App.scss. You can define the light and dark class into your App.scss or into Navbar.scss. @import also work to import sass files into other sass file.

```
@use 'Navbar/Navbar';
.nav {
   .light { //...}
   .dark { //...}
}
```

or

```
@import 'Navbar/Navbar';
.nav {
   .light { //...}
   .dark { //...}
}
```

Comment: Well, i tried doing what you suggested, adding a ```.site-nav.dark{ // }``` to my ```.nav``` in ```_Navbar.scss```  (this is what i need) and also doing the same thing in my ```App.scss``` but it doesn't work...